# How to make sure that some certain set belong to sigma -algebra?

Tags: real-analysis

I try to solve some cerain question about the integral involing measure.
Here is the problem:
if $f:X\rightarrow  \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is any measurable functio,and measure space $(X,\mathscr{X},\mu)$,then
$\int_{A}fd\mu=0$ ,if $\mu(A)=0$
Here is my proof:
1.Assume that $f\ge0$
$ \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$          2.$\int_{A}fd\mu=\int f\chi_{A}d\mu=\sup_{0\le\phi\le f\chi_{A}}$
$\{ \int \phi d\mu\}$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$3. According to simple Approximation lemma and monotone convergence theorem,there exists simple a function$ \quad $ $\phi_{n}(x)\rightarrow f(x) \quad as\quad n\rightarrow \infty$.

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$4.I suppose that $\phi_{n}(x) \quad take\quad c_{0},c_{1},...c_{N}, $ they are different values,and corresponding to $E_{i},0\le i\le N$,I get that
$\int\phi_{n}d\mu=\sum_{i=0}^{N}c_{i}\mu(E_{i})$,if $c_{i}\neq 0,$then $E_{i}\subset A
   $,so $\int\phi_{n}d\mu=0$,

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$5.thus  $\int_{A}fd\mu$=$\lim_{n\to\infty}$  $\int\phi_{n}d\mu=0$

my question:Is it correct that$A\subset\mathscr{X} $and $E_{i}\subset \mathscr{X},$if so,how to make sure that holds?

Comment: You can't even write $\mu(A)$ unless $A\in\mathscr{X}$, right? So if you state that $\mu(A))= 0$, then you are implicitly stating that $A\in\mathscr{X}$.

Answer (score 0):

小辉，$A$ is measurable, i.e., belongs to the sigma-algebra, because it is given that $\mu(A)=0$. The $E_i$'s are also measurable, because the simple functions $\phi_n$ are measurable, and the $E_i$'s are the level sets of these simple functions, that is, the sets where they take a certain value. Such sets are also measurable, so they belong to the sigma algebra as well.

Comment: thank you,Sir,I misunderstanding some basic concepts,Does  my proof have  some defects?otherwise,How do you know and type the character of my name?that is amaing.